# SASS / CSS with different font size based on user preference

Tags: css, sass

I am working on a style sheet for a micro frontend that has three different view types (Touch, Standard and Compact). Touch and Standard are selected automatically based on your device, but you can always change it via user preferences.

Based on your selected view type the fonts, margins and paddings are affected. There is no direct relation between these 3, for example, in compact mode the padding is much smaller in relation to font-size than what it is in touch mode.

Since it is a micro-frontend I cannot use rems and set the font-size on the html tag, since it will affect all the composed micro-frontends.

Using SASS, what I have done is create a function to converts px to rem and I use that function all over to calculate to correct font-sizes, margins and padding in rem for the different components and view-types.

At top level I have a scss file that looks something like this

```
// The different font-sizes
$font-size-standard: 14;
$font-size-touch: 16;
$font-size-compact: 11;

// namespaced to not interfere with other styles 
.toolkit {
    $font-size: $font-size-standard;
    @include 'someComponents';
}

.toolkit.touch {
    $font-size: $font-size-touch;
    @include 'someComponents';
}

.toolkit.compact {
    $font-size: $font-size-compact;
    @include 'someComponents';
}
```

In the components there is logic and calculations based on the selected font-size.

This approach works, but I end up with a massive css file, since everything is triplicated.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for CSS variables

Comment: I hear you man, but I need to support ie11 :(

Comment: Not sure this is feasible without using `rem` or CSS variables.